# Exception handling: what exception to raise

Tags: python, exception

I am writing a python function that accepts certain parameters. I would like to make sure one of the parameter's value is a string of specific custom format. If it doesn't match the format I would like to raise an exception. Is it appropriate to raise one of the built-in exception and if yes which one?

I looked here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html# but couldn't pin down to a specific one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as it provides a detailed and explicit error message, you can use a built-in one -  [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError), for example, looks logical here.

Another option would be to create a custom one:

```
class InvalidFormatError(ValueError):
    pass
```

There are relevant threads on SO that, I hope, would help you to decide which option to choose:

- [When to use custom exceptions vs. existing exceptions vs. generic exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588265/when-to-use-custom-exceptions-vs-existing-exceptions-vs-generic-exceptions)
- [Is it OK to raise a built-in exception, but with a different message, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180577/is-it-ok-to-raise-a-built-in-exception-but-with-a-different-message-in-python)

Comment: If you create a custom exception class, it should probably still be a subclass of ValueError for this use case (not just a direct subclass of `Exception`).

Answer (score 3):

What you describe sounds like a [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError):

> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError):

> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError.

That it is raised by built in functions doesn't mean you can't `raise` it too.